# MonoTouch - UIButton with custom gradient

Tags: xamarin.ios

Trying to create a custom UIButton in MonoTouch using CGGradientLayer.

Following along with a few tutorials I've found online such as:

http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_custom_uibuttons.php#gradients

So far can't get anything to display, currently just an empty button.

Here's my code which is running from ViewDidLoad:

```
var gradient = new CAGradientLayer();

gradient.Colors = new MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColor[]
{
    new MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColor(115f, 181f, 216f, 1f),
    new MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColor(35f, 101f, 136f, 1f)
};

gradient.Locations = new NSNumber[]
{
    .5f,
    1f
};

gradient.Frame = btnSearch.Layer.Bounds;

btnSearch.Layer.AddSublayer(gradient);

btnSearch.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
```

Any ideas what I've missed?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like that constructor of CGColor accepts RGB values in 0.0f-1.0f float range, not 0-255 integers.

As an alternative, try to set CGColors by UIColors:

```
gradient.Colors = new MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColor[]
{
    UIColor.FromRGB (115, 181, 216).CGColor,
    UIColor.FromRGB (35, 101, 136).CGColor
};
```

BTW, nice blue gradient :)